# steam libgl error. wont load swrast_dri.so and swrast

Tags: drivers, steam

I finished downloading steam but it won't run. this is the output when I tried to start it.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast"
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what graphic card you use,seems to me from here that you use open source driver and Steam not run usually from 1st with open source driver,but it possible to make it run..also double check that your Ubuntu is 64 bit OS as you downloaded 64 bit version of Steam launcher..
so step by step→we can see if your system is 64bit,and many more from command `uname -a` and then what is your graphic adapter enough will be output from command `lspci | grep VGA`. Then we can proceed further..
also you as ordinary user can see that if you go in upper right corner, and click on your user name and click on "about computer" , after with that information, we can proceed further.

But you can try this workaround in meantime: with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> start terminal and run:

```
cd ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

and then start Steam,result will depend on your graphic card ...
first line is valid if you use 32 bit system,and 2nd line is if you use 64bit system ,both lines are valid if you use open source driver for your graphic...
Well, as for Ubuntu 15.10 is still possible to use proprietary AMD `fglrx` driver I will recommend to not upgrade to 16.04, but more detailed and precise answer I or we really need to know what graphic card you use, good is to be sure about is it 32 or 64 bit system, etc..

As if you are still on Ubuntu 15.10 sure for best results with Steam will be to use proprietary drivers,and not open source ones... but with Ubuntu 16.04 there will be no more support for `fglrx` AMD proprietary driver, even to manually installation.. but will be `amdgpu` and `amdgpu-pro` drivers for newer and new amd cards..so really iIneed to know more details to give you precise answer exactly for your computer that will fit just you.

Comment: This is more appropriate for a comment.

Comment: add lines of two (solution,workaround) commands for 32bit and 64 bit if he use and plan to use open source driver with Steam..and explanation of possibility with Ubuntu 15.10 with Steam.

Comment: Try to write in a more orderly way too. It is three dots, not two dots (...). To format code, use Ctrl+K, or enclose the text with `. [In this website](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) you can find many more hints about how to format an answer or question. Don't rush. Be considered to the readers.

Comment: thanks luchonacho i will try to format code with Ctrl K next time..